# Gmail not delivering email even though giving 250 OK

Tags: email, cakephp, gmail, postfix-mta, dovecot

I have configured my postfix and dovecot correctly, I can send and receive email on my server.

Here`s the snag - if I send email from Thunderbird via SMTP on my server, it gets delivered to gmail within seconds, I can see it in my inbox, no problem there (this gives me the notion, that SMTP itself is working just fine).

However if I try to send email from my web app (written in CakePHP3), the postfix shows response from gmail servers as 250 OK, I see timestamp, token, everything. However email never shows in my inbox when I log in to gmail.

Since email gets delivered from Thunderbird and not from app I guess there is something wrong with transporter in CakePHP, here`s the config:

```
'EmailTransport' => [
    'default' => [
        'className' => 'Smtp',
        'host' => 'mydomain.com',
        'port' => 587,
        'timeout' => 30,
        'username' => 'myuser',
        'password' => 'mypassword',
        'tls' => true,
    ]
]
```

However the app has no problem delivering email to my work email account. Also I tried sending email to my girlfriend's account (she doesn`t use gmail) and it is delivered as well. Both times correctly via TLS.

Any thoughts what does gmail want that Thunderbird has and the app might not be sending ? I used diff on email source sent from app and TB and could not see anything relevant.

Any thought would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check your GMail junk folder? It might be blocking the email due to things like IP address reputation, SPF settings, that sort of thing.

Comment: Yes, checked spam, trash, everything. And since email is delivered within second when sent via Thunderbird I guess it has something to do with CakePHP. Both Thunderbird and CakePHP use the same SMTP server.

Comment: You said you diffed the email source. Did that include all the headers? Or just the content?

Comment: Everything, including headers of course. I suspect that`s where the reason for delivering vs. not delivering is hiding.

Comment: Maybe show those, or at least the differences. You may not have seen anything relevant, but someone else might.

Comment: So I have an update - gmail delivers emails which DO NOT contain any URL. If i send email with url (even if that url is gmail.com) my email is not delivered (gsmtp still returns 250 OK, but email doesn`t show up in my inbox). Email gets delivered, when the url is http://localhost), bud anything else gets blocked. Has anyonve encountered this ? I also tried using SendGrid (free) but no luck, emails with URLs are still blocked. What ticks me the most is there is no info, no bounce email, nothing. I have send 2 emails to gmail support, without any response yet. This happens for plaintext and html